# liquibase invoked through maven, unable to set custom property

Tags: liquibase

My liquibase file has following sql element:

```
<sql splitStatements="false">
  GRANT insert,select,update,delete ON ${database.defaultSchemaName}.someTable TO ${db.appUser}
</sql>
```

if I invoke maven like:

```
mvn liquibase:update -Ddb.appUser=VALUE
```

it works. But what if I'd like to specify it somewhere in pom.xml? Assume some developer profile, relieving me from setting the variable over and over, and be able to build like:

```
mvn -Pdevel liquibase:update
```

I tried to set it in maven properties, but it's not picked there. So how do we set properties in maven to be substituted in liquibase scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually find it:

one have to bridge maven properties into "system properties", it can be done as:

```
<systemProperties>
  <db.appUser>${mavenVariable}</db.appUser>
</systemProperties>
```

or just provide literal instead of maven variable.